# Exception: addEvent is not a recognised Objective C method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native, react-native-bridge

I'm porting swift class to ReactNative.

my CalendarManager.Swift class

> CalendarManager.Swift

```
 import Foundation;


import UIKit;
// CalendarManager.swift

@objc(CalendarManager)
class CalendarManager: NSObject {

  @objc
  func addEvent(_name: String, location: String, date: NSNumber) -> Void {
    // Date is ready to use!

      NSLog("%@ %@ %S", _name, location, date);
   // self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

}
```

my objective C class

> CalendarManager.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(CalendarManager , NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(addEvent: (NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location date:(NSNumber *)date)

@end
```

> SwiftBridge-header

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

Please let me know how to reduce that following error.

[image]

Comment: try updating the function as `@objc
  func addEvent(_name: String, location location: String, date date: NSNumber) -> Void`

Comment: sam error. Can you check

Comment: there should be a space in `_ name`, please try that way, `@objc func addEvent(_ name: String`

Answer (score 0):

Try to Provide a **method description for Objective-C**.

Your fn:

```
@objc
  func addEvent(_name: String, location: String, date: NSNumber)...
```

Try changing it to:

```
@objc(addEvent:::)
  func addEvent(name: String, location: String, date: NSNumber)...
```

where, ':' represents a parameter, since the function is receiving 3, so there would be 3 colons or you can pass variable names as well, though it won't matter.